# every time i try to test run i run in to an error The name 'Player' does not exist in the current context. i cant find a solution

Tags: c#

I am making a game and in the game im trying to make the enemy go towards the player when the player steps into the sight of the enemy. I cant figure out how to make the name (player) mean anything im very new at this its my second attempt on makin a game please help me im very confused im running c#

```cs
using System.Collections;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using UnityEngine;

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
  private Transform _target;

  [SerializeField] private float _speed = 9;
    
   void Awake() {
       _target = FindObjectOfType(Player)().transform;
   }

   void update() {

       transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position,_target.position, _speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `typeof` operator instead of passing the class name.

```cs
void Awake() {
    _target = FindObjectOfType(typeof(Player))().transform;
}
```